# iOS::Button on navigation bar only appears on root view controller

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have hundreds of view controllers I'm dealing with.  I have the root view controller embedded in a navigation controller.  I would like to add a 'Home' button to the navigation bar of every view except the root view.  How can I do this without having to add a button to every view in UI Builder?

Answer (score 1):

Subclass your navigation controller and explicitly add a default BarButtonItem to it so that it is defaulted on every view.  And on your root view, remove it by setting navigationController.rightBarItem = nil or leftBar... Whatever is your case.

---

Apple Navigation Controller reference = https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html